# Error "Bad data on line N" en gnuplot

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, gnuplot

Me gustaría realizar un histograma en base a una serie de datos que tengo en un archivo .txt. Los diez primeros datos de este archivo son:

```
Albania 1970
Antigua and Barbuda 11
Argentina 82219
Armenia 1905
Aruba 101
Australia 70111
Austria 50073
Azerbaijan 1656
Bahamas 93
Bahrain 463
```

Sin embargo, no entiendo muy bien cómo se utiliza GNUplot y estoy teniendo errores al ejecutar un script que he hecho. El script tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
#!/bin/bash

set title "Título"
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set style data histogram
plot 'fichero.txt'
```

Al ejecutar el script, el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
gnuplot ./grafico.plot

plot 'fichero.txt' 
     ^
"./grafico.plot" line 5: Bad data on line 1 of file fichero.txt
```

¿Por qué me salta un error en los datos del fichero?
No tengo mucha experiencia con gnuplot y no entiendo que podría estar fallando, así que cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿quizás el problema puede estar en que los datos que tengo están en una sola línea y no en dos columnas diferentes? Es que esos datos los saqué al utilizar ```awk``` sobre otro fichero. En caso de que pudiera ser el error, se podría separar en dos columnas el fichero?

Comment: El comando que utilicé sobre el fichero para obtener las dos columnas que muestro es: `awk -F, '{a[$1]+=$5} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' fichero.csv`. Con el comando lo que conseguí fue imprimir la columna de los países y la suma de otra columna en base a los países. ¿Quizás el error estaría aquí? Es que he decidido meter la salida de este comando en un archivo CSV y veo que me aparecen las dos columnas en una sola, cuando necesitaría de dos columnas para poder hacer un gráfico.

Comment: El error te dice *Datos incorrectos en la línea 1 del archivo fichero.txt*, podría ser por los países que tienes en la columna. Podrías especificar la columna dos con `plot 'fichero.txt' using 2` para mostrar el gráfico solo con los datos numéricos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uno de los problemas es que los nombres de algunos de los paises contienen espacios. Esos nombres deben estar protegidos por comillas, de modo que tu fichero debería contener:

```
Albania 1970
"Antigua and Barbuda" 11
Argentina 82219
Armenia 1905
Aruba 101
Australia 70111
Austria 50073
Azerbaijan 1656
Bahamas 93
Bahrain 463
```

Otro problema es que, por defecto, gnuplot espera que la primera columna contenga números (que serán usados como las coordenadas x de los puntos a pintar) y la segunda columna contenga datos (que serían la altura de las barras a pintar). Pero tu fichero no se pliega a la estructura esperada y de ahí el error que obtienes.

Por suerte gnuplot es muy flexible. Al comando `plot` le puedes especificar qué columnas del fichero quieres usar como datos y cuáles como "etiquetas" de los tics del eje. En tu caso la especificación sería `using 2:xtic(1)` que significa que use la columna 2 como datos (eje Y), y la columna 1 como etiquetas para los tics del eje x.

Por otro lado los nombres de los paises son muy largos y se solapan unos con otros, de modo que para que se puedan leer conviene ponerlos girados -90 grados. Eso requiere también ampliar el margen inferior de la figura para que quepan enteros.

Todo esto lo hace el siguiente script:

```
set title "Título"
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.5
set xtics rotate by -90 offset 0,-.2
set bmargin 10
set key off

plot 'fichero.txt' using 2:xtic(1) with boxes
```

Con el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia! Al hacer lo que me dices consigo que se ejecute el script y veo como el gráfico aparece un instante y desaparece enseguida. Es decir, se abre y se cierra la ventana del gráfico en un instantte. ¿Eso puede ser problema del paquete gnuplot que tengo instalado?

Comment: No, ese es el comportamiento normal de gnuplot. Para que permanezca en pantalla debes ejecutarlo de otra forma. Primero ejecutas `gnuplot` sin parámetros, y una vez te aparece un prompt que dice `gnuplot>` ahi pones `load "fichero"` (donde `"fichero"` es el script con los comandos gnuplot). Esto te permite además seguir dando comandos gnuplot para variar el aspecto de la figura. Si prefieres también puedes lanzar `gnuplot -p fichero` y con la opción -p permanecerá abierta la ventana de la gráfica.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias de verdad! Buenísima respuesta y muy bien explicada!