# Añadir comillas a una salida con bash, awk, sed u otro tipo de herramientas

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Esta tarde realicé una pregunta para ver cómo realizar un gráfico mediante gnuplot. Dejo por aquí el enlace:

[Problemas a la hora de utilizar gnupot en bash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413541/problemas-a-la-hora-de-utilizar-gnupot-en-bash)

Obtuve una respuesta bastante buena por parte del usuario abulafia. Lo que he hecho, gracias a la respuesta de este usuario, ha sido un gráfico de barras donde se puede ver un número de países y unos valores En su respuesta me decía que para poder graficar los países, aquellos que tuvieran espacios deberían estar entre comillas. Es decir, rescatando el fichero del post que realicé, estos son parte de mis datos:

```
Albania 1970
Antigua and Barbuda 11
Argentina 82219
Armenia 1905
Aruba 101
Australia 70111
Austria 50073
Azerbaijan 1656
Bahamas 93
Bahrain 463
```

Y abulafia me dijo que deberían estar así:

```
Albania 1970
"Antigua and Barbuda" 11
Argentina 82219
Armenia 1905
Aruba 101
Australia 70111
Austria 50073
Azerbaijan 1656
Bahamas 93
Bahrain 463
```

Entonces, mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo obtener una salida donde los países que tengan espacios aparezcan entre comillas?

He intentado lo siguiente con awk:

```
awk -v OFS="'" '{print "", $1, $2""}' fichero.txt | head -10
```

Pero con esto solo consigo poner entre comillas la primera palabra:

```
'Albania'1970
'Antigua'and
'Argentina'82219
'Armenia'1905
'Aruba'101
'Australia'70111
'Austria'50073
'Azerbaijan'1656
'Bahamas'93
'Bahrain'463
```

Como se ve, en el país Antigua and Barbuda obtengo 'Antigua' and. Esto me sucede con el resto de países con espacios.

También lo he intentado con sed pero solo consigo que se me imprima toda la fila entre comillas:

```
sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' suicidiosxpais.txt  | head -10

"Albania 1970"
"Antigua and Barbuda 11"
"Argentina 82219"
"Armenia 1905"
"Aruba 101"
"Australia 70111"
"Austria 50073"
"Azerbaijan 1656"
"Bahamas 93"
"Bahrain 463"
```

Por ahora, más que centrarme en aquellos países con espacios, lo que estoy intentando es ponerle comillas a todos los países del fichero, porque entiendo que si todos tienen comillas también será posible realizar el gráfico.

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Y si usas la coma como delimitador?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 awk '{last=$NF; $NF=""; gsub(/ $/,""); print "\""$0"\"", last}' fichero.txt
```

Cómo funciona:

- Con `last=$NF` capturo la última palabra de la línea
- Con `$NF=""` borro esa última palabra, por lo que en `$0`, que representa la línea, me queda solo el nombre del país (y un espacio final)
- Con `gsub(/ $/,"")` borro el espacio final de `$0`
- Finalmente con el `print` imprimo el `$0` entre comillas y después, tras un espacio, la palabra que había capturado en `last`.

Ejemplo de entrada:

```
Albania 1970
Antigua and Barbuda 11
Argentina 82219
Armenia 1905
Aruba 101
Australia 70111
Austria 50073
Azerbaijan 1656
Bahamas 93
Bahrain 463
```

Produce la salida:

```
"Albania" 1970
"Antigua and Barbuda" 11
"Argentina" 82219
"Armenia" 1905
"Aruba" 101
"Australia" 70111
"Austria" 50073
"Azerbaijan" 1656
"Bahamas" 93
"Bahrain" 463
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo abulafia!! No pensé que me responderías de nuevo, espero no haberte molestado! Muy útil la respuesta y también la explicación!!

Comment: @abulafia, curiosamente hice el mismo script en `awk` que tú ¡Incluso con los mismos nombres de variables! Lo cual me hizo reír mucho. Sólo que yo desistí de usar esto porque noto extraño tener que borrar el espacio extra con `gsub`

Answer (score 3):

Otra alternativa con `sed` es:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*) ([[:digit:]]+)$/"\1" \2/g' fichero.txt
"Albania" 1970
"Antigua and Barbuda" 11
"Argentina" 82219
... etc
```

Con lo cual tan sólo busco todos los caracteres antes de un espacio `(.*)`  (`sed` los asigna al grupo 1), luego una cadena con varios números que están antes del final de línea `([[:digit:]]+)$` (`sed` los asigna al grupo 2).

Después, le indicamos a `sed` que imprima el primer grupo encerrado con comillas `"\1"`, seguido de un espacio luego del grupo dos (el número)  `\2`.

Otra opción semejante pero con `gawk` es:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(.*) ([[:digit:]]+)$/,"\"\\1\" \\2", "g", $0)}' fichero.txt
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias Cuauhtli!! Gran aporte!! :)

Comment: pensé exactamente la misma solución en Sed!